# AEM /etc.clientlibs not accessible through Dispatcher

Tags: java, aem, apache-felix, sling, crx

When requesting a page on dispatcher I am seeing this in my Publish instance **error.log**

```
18.12.2019 22:13:05.563 *INFO* [x.x.x.x [1576707185560] GET /etc.clientlibs/project/clientlibs/clientlib-all.fd5c5f2e8418f9ae1aa923efb9e7ad95.js HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.ClientLibraryProxyServlet Proxy request to /etc.clientlibs/project/clientlibs/clientlib-all.fd5c5f2e8418f9ae1aa923efb9e7ad95.js not supported.
```

Consequently the **etc.clientlibs** are not loading in the dispatcher, it sends back a 404 instead.

Filter rules seem to allow clientlibs by default`/0002 { /type "allow" /url "/etc.clientlibs/*" }`

I did a little digging online and found the following potential workaround:

1. Allow **anonymous** *read* access on `/etc`.
2. Explicitly *deny* **anonymous** *read* access on 1st level children of `/etc` to make sure you don’t allow things through.

While this seems to fix the issue momentarily I think this is at best a workaround.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem and how to fix this without changing permissions that are OOTB ?

Thanks,

Nicola

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using?

Comment: I am running AEM 6.5.2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much troubleshooting I believe I figured out a solution to my issue. My sling mapping needed modifying from

```
sling:internalRedirect="[/content/project/us/en,/]"
```

to

```
sling:internalRedirect="[/,/content/project/us/en]"
```

After this change was made everything resolves properly without having to change OOTB permissions. Hope this helps others.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, anonymous access was ok. As soon as the user logged in through Sling, they got a 404 through the dispatcher. Otherwise direct access to publisher was ok ¯\_(ツ)_/¯